# What is the cause of these WaitForFPS spikes and dips?

Tags: unity, profiler

In Unity, moving the player causes the camera to jitter. I went to the Profiler, and I saw these spikes:
[image: Unity Profiler Spikes]
On further inspection, all the yellow spikes were WaitForFPS(). I've tried every VSync setting in quality options, but none of them seem to fix this issue.

Comment: Does http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/239193/wait-for-trigger-fps-profiler.html help?

Answer (score 1):

`WaitForFPS` isn't really an issue (it has a specific purpose in attaining the target frame-rate of your game).

Is your camera getting moved in the [`LateUpdate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) Callback? The most common reason for camera jitter in camera movement scripts is using Update, which is causes the target's movement to happen after the camera's movement is updated, leaving it always "catching up".